# Colon between "that is" and formal definition

Tags: punctuation, formality, writing-style, colons

Is it appropriate to use "that is" followed by a colon when defining something formally? I have the following example:

> Let γ be the set of groups that hold variables accessed by C, that is:
>
> γ = {g : ∃v accessed by C, such that v ∈ g}.

Would that be appropriate in terms of punctuation and style?

Comment: You should ask this on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't think so. The mathematical example is just an illustration of a formal definition. It could be applied to any other formal text. The question is solely about how to write properly such a definition in the English language.

Comment: In mathematical writing, the ideal is that mathematics should be punctuated in the same way as if it were ordinary text. You can bend the rules if the ordinary use of punctuation makes things confusing. But I don't see why a comma is any more confusing than a colon in the above example. If it were a long definition that wasn't set off as a centered equation, this might be another matter (but in this case, I'd recommend not using "that is" to introduce it).

Comment: I like what @PeterShor said. I found [this rule](http://leo.stcloudstate.edu/punct/col-semi.html) for use of colons: _Use a colon to separate an explanation, rule, or example from a preceding independent clause_. I'm no expert in the matter, but, it seems like, when you add the "that is", the preceding clause loses its independence.

Comment: @PeterShor, you mean I should just write "(...) accessed by C, γ = (...)"? I don't see how to avoid rephrasing the definition completely when removing "that is".

Comment: @J.R., doesn't the fact that, in the above example, one clause explains (formally repeats) the other make them dependent?

Comment: @Eduardo: If it's a long and complicated definition using words (the case when I said you should avoid using 'that is'), I would at least put it in its own sentence. It might even require several sentences, and making them all clauses of one sentence doesn't improve clarity. Otherwise, I'd just use the standard English punctuation for "that is".

Comment: Or could you maybe use "in other words:"?

Comment: After thinking about it, I don't think there's anything wrong with a colon after "that is". If you had a long list after "that is" in ordinary prose, you could definitely use a colon. And similarly, I think if you had a complicated prose definition after "that is" in a math paper, you could also use a colon. I don't think you need one in OP's example, though.

Comment: I don't think the equation is served by introducing it with *that is* at all. I'd prefer removing it: "variables accessed by C:" The colon is the only signal needed. In math, we used to introduce the equation by saying *such that*.

Answer (score 4):

With regard to punctuating *that is*, we follow Jane Straus's [Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation](http://grammarbook.com/punctuation/semicolons.asp). It is preferable to use a semicolon before *that is* and a comma after *is*.

> XXX; that is, XXX.

With regard to the best way to define something formally, that is not in the scope of this site.

Comment: I meant to ask if it was alright to use this kind of punctuation when defining something formally. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: -1 You did not say if the OP's version was wrong, which is what, I think **is** the question.

Comment: @Kris: Is everything necessarily wrong if it's not right ? Of course it's understandeable, and it's not the preferred way. I don't see how it could be called wrong *per se*. FTR, it's tagged [style].

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks How did *understandeable* make it thru' the spell check? :)

Comment: Oh, oops, thanks. Common mistake of mine I'm afraid :/ (Lemme edit! >_<)

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete. If you had a long list after "that is" in ordinary prose, you should put a colon after it. Similarly, if you have a long definition after "that is" in a math paper, you should put a colon after it. But for the OP's example, my feeling is that a comma works fine.